# Mysql reports "unknown variable pass" after upgrading from 5.5.41 -> 5.7.5 on Debian

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, my.cnf

We have the following problem after upgrading MySQL 5.5.41 (pre-installed on our Debian Wheezy LAMP server from Hetzner) to 5.7.5 version (downloaded from mysql.com).

After updgrading from the default Hetzner configuration to 5.7.5 version, we have the following situation: packages installed successfully, mysql deamon is running, but mysql, mysql_upgrade and other tools fail to start.

They report the same error:
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'pass='

Such variable does not exist in my.cnf. Neither I can't find this variable somewhere else.

During upgrade, I've set a new mysql root password (of course).

Question: where this pass variable can be hardcoded, and how can I solve this problem?

Backup was made. No data was created yet. New version is installed via APT repo. Password reset & database init procedures do not help.

Thank you,
Georgy Blagodatov

Comment: You are aware that MySQL 5.7 is not production ready, right? It is a development release.  Also, you cannot upgrade 5.5->5.7  you need to upgrade to 5.6 first. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Right, I know mysql 5.7 is under development, maybe I tried it to early. I missed the fact I cannot upgrate 5.5->5.7 directly. Now I removed 5.7 (sudo apt-get update / remove / autoremove), switch APT repository to 5.6 (sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config), but when I run apt-get install mysql-server then, it tries to install 5.5, not 5.6. And it fails to install it.

Comment: Can't help you on that, sorry. I'm a CentOS-person. What you can do though, is you can use the binary/generic release from MySQL's website if you only need 5.6 to upgrade in order to move along to 5.7.

Comment: If you aren't, try using the dotdeb repository as it'll neatly give you access to MySQL 5.6 https://www.dotdeb.org/category/mysql/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used *strace* to see what's going on. For me it was in ...

**/root/.my.cnf**.

*mysql* also tried to open ...

**/root/.mylogin.cnf**

... so that's also a candidate.

Comment: exactly, Hetzner has put a hardcoded password into such a hidden file which could not be even grep-ed)

Comment: Yep, that was a Hetzner box.